# Execute Task.WhenAll(tasks) to hit ADO.NET calls to fetch data in parallel for improving timing performance

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, task, task-parallel-library

I have a stored procedure that fetches data of 1.1 million records. It's taking a time of 1+ minute.

Please note that there are no column filters on the query hence I cannot apply any non-clustered index to improve timing performance.

But I have the option to send pagination parameters `"start"` & `"limit"` to the stored procedure, using those I can fetch a few records at a time. My idea is to fetch 200,000 records at a time. As it takes 10 seconds to fetch 200,000 records. My idea is it should take just 10 seconds to fetch 1.1+ million records by making 6 database calls in parallel.

I tried using the below code to fetch data in parallel but it is still taking 1+ minute.

Can anyone explain why it takes the same time? How can I improve timing performance from the caller C# code?

Here `Ranges` is a a dictionary with key values:

`Ranges = [0, 200000], [200000, 400000], [400000, 600000], [600000, 800000], [800000, 1000000], [1000000, 15555]`

```
var dataSetQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<DataSet>();
var tasks = ranges.Select(async range =>
{
   var paramlist = new List<SqlParameter>();
   paramlist.AddParameter("start", range.Key);
   paramlist.AddParameter("limit", range.Value);
   var dataSet = await _databaseManager.ExecuteDataSetAsync(MySP, paramlist, ConnectionStringName);
   dataSetQueue.Enqueue(dataSet);
});

await Task.WhenAll(tasks); // <-- Issue: Still takes 1+ minutes to execute. why & how ?
```

Comment: Where is located the database server? Is it in the same machine? In a different machine in the local network? In a remote machine with internet connection?

Comment: What is _databaseManager, and is it designed for concurrency? Also: if you're talking to the same resource, concurrency may have limited impact - or can even have negative impact (unless you have spare capacity at both the server and network, and there's no harmful isolation/locking/etc feedback)

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Database server is at a remote location. Its not local.

Comment: @MarcGravell _databaseManager is a wrapper of ADO.net calls. It is an Asynchronous  method so I think it's designed for concurrency.

Comment: If you increase the pressure on the database and network, why do think it will magically reduce the time to get the results? Parallelism doesn't necessarily means better performance.

Comment: Do you really need all the data in memory? What are you doing with the data?

Comment: Databases are in most cases primarily under IO pressure. Most RDBMSs are parallelized anyway and can read as fast as the disk allows, so parallelizing requests is just going to slow it down further. Better disks (SSDs) and better network will help a lot. I suggest you reconsider the necessity of downloading so much data in the first place

Comment: Since you connect to the server remotely, I expect that the bottleneck is the network bandwidth. In which case you can't really do much, other than reducing the transferred data or compressing them.

Comment: @MudassirHussain async says nothing whatsoever about "designed for concurrency". Most types with async methods will explode in a pile of mess if you overlap operations, exactly the same as you would get if you used multiple threads with non-async methods. Designing for concurrency is a very specific - and rare - feature.